# How do I center the text in a slicer excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

because there is no options under the slicer modify page to center text, I am hoping for a VBA solution to center the text inside a slicer.

is this possible? I just have a column of numbers in a slicer that look dorky when left aligned.

[image]

Comment: While I'm sure some of the users here understand your question as is, it would be helpful to post a screenshot of what you are describing so that future users could benefit from this Q and A.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to accomplish this with slicer styles and vba but was unable to figure out a way to doing it. The only thing that kinda makes it look better was adding columns to the slicer to and re-sizing it. With single digit number you can resize it to appear center but with larger numbers the left align becomes apparent. Maybe this will help somewhat.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the post, i'm going to hold out on a VBA solution though :(